# How to get at the value of a specific array ID

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I have an array called $fields. If I do this:

```
foreach ($fields as $id => $field) {
  print $id."<br />";
}
```

I get:

```
field_track_icon
field_session_number
field_job_title
```

I know this is totally simple, but my brain just will not come up with the answer, and I can't seem to google the right terms. How can I wrap the foreach in an if statement that's based on which id is being processed?

Pseudocode would be:

```
if($fields['field_session_number'] == 'S2') {
   foreach($fields as $id=>$field) {
      print $field->content;
   }
}
```

Basically, I'm working with a single record of data returned in the $fields array. I only want to print out the individual field properties (`$field->content` or `$field->prefix`, for example) if the id of the field being processed is S2.

Comment: I cannot figure out what is meant by "id of the field being processed".

Comment: The pseudocode would already work, but I guess you don't want to iterate over the 'field_session_number' key?

Comment: @wallyk I think session_nr is the id

Comment: It will help if you can show the result of `print_r($fields)`.

Comment: @wallyk = id is the $id variable. When I loop through using the foreach, the $id of the first array item is field_session_number. I need to be able to run the foreach conditionally.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get element with specific key, you don't have to make for cycle - you just get it.

```
$field = $fields['field_session_number'];
echo $field->content;
echo $field->prefix;
```

If ID is not array key, but same as content or prefix, then you need for cycle:

```
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if ($field->id === 'S2') {
        echo $field->content;
    }
}
```